# Allowing iframe content to load from served public js file using rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe

How can I offer a js file from my rails backend and allow it to display the site in an iframe? Is it possible to do this without using the `ALLOWALL` x frame option?

The JS file appends an iframe with the source at `http://localhost:3000/embed` , but i'm getting an error when I try and put `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/myscript.js"></script>` in a separate html file for testing.

Here is the error:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:3000/embed' in a frame because it set 
'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

and here is my JS file:

```
function  myscript() {
    var slg = document.getElementById("slg");
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost:3000/embed');
    iframe.style.width = '600px';
    iframe.style.height = '600px';
    slg.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Can I set any rails options that allow the site to be loaded via the script, but not for sites?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to offer this JS file to any number of sites, so a specific one isn't an option. Plus I don't believe that header is supported by chrome